# Reset Existing xDB Contacts Pipeline Dynamics Plugin not resetting values on xdb

Tags: xdb, pipelines, data-exchange-framework, dynamics-crm-module

I'm using Data Exchange Framework 1.4.1 (rev. 170818) and Dynamics CRM Connect 1.4.1 (rev. 170818).

The Reset Existing xDB Contacts Pipeline doesn't remove marketing lists values from the xDB Contacts.
Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

The pipeline is trying to set the marketing list property to null. By default, a null value will not overwrite an existing value.

To change this:

1. Open the Content Editor
2. Select your tenant
3. Navigate to `Value Mapping Sets > Clear CRM List Membership on xDB Contact > Marketing Lists`
4. Untick the field `Ignore null values`
5. Save the item

Comment: I've already done that nothing changed...